# How can I access GET parameters from a Facebook iframe tab using PHP?

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-iframe

I am creating a Facebook iframe application, and need to use some `$_GET` variables.  This works fine for the application, using something similar to what is described [in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3175300/facebook-iframe-application-how-to-pass-data-from-url-query-string).

However, when I use the app as a tab inside of a facebook fan page, I can't figure out how to pass the variable, or retrieve it.  The URL for the site looks like this:

```
http://www.facebook.com/pages/(Page Name)/(Page ID)?sk=app_(app ID)
```

And if I try to simply tack a `&var1=val1` to the end it doesn't work (Which I didn't really expect it to...) at all.

Is there a way that I can get to the displayed file, the home.php, in the url so I can tack the get variable onto the end and use it?  Right now, there's no way to make it so that a copy-pasted url directs to a specific page inside the application.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to pass JSON via the app_data parameter. See https://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/signed_request/ for details.

Comment: This seems as if the app_data section of the JSON is a good way to pass the variable on, but it doesn't make it so that the URL is changed in a way that will make a copy-past URL load the correct variable, correct?