# Passing values to iframe in Facebook App tab

Tags: php, facebook

Can you add a query variable to a Facebook App URL? For example, I have this URL http://www.facebook.com/blahblah/app_97922829890, can I use:
http://www.facebook.com/blahblah/app_97922829890/xuser/1?

I wish to display customised content for individual users on a Facebook app tab within an IFrame. Suppose I wish to send User A (who has id=1) an email with the following link:
http://www.facebook.com/blahblah/app_97922829890/xuser/1
and then User B (who has id=23) and email with this link
http://www.facebook.com/blahblah/app_97922829890/xuser/23

IS there anyway I can access xuser and its value in my iframe on my Facebook app tab using php in the iframe, so I can display a message personally to them based on their preferences in the DB that is on my server?

Any help will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Facebook Application Tab -> External Linking with PHP](http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/questions/3524501/facebook-application-tab-external-linking-with-php)

Comment: (the accepted answer there has an example of how to do this)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible, simply add the query string to your app URL and it will be passed on

See this: [Facebook iFrame application: How to pass data from URL Query String](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3175300/facebook-iframe-application-how-to-pass-data-from-url-query-string)